# JQuery animation and slideUp delay issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap navbar, and above the navigation links I have some text which I want to hide when the user scrolls down. Also, i want the navbar to be fixed top.

I am using a `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` to hide/show the text above the navbar, and I am using Jquery `animate()` to modify the navbar's height. (I need to have it's height explicit because of CSS reasons irrelevant to this issue)

The problem is that when I scroll to the top, the `animate()` gets queued after the `slideDown()` (Maybe it is not queued but it has some unwanted delay), which does not happen in the scrolling-down case. I want them to be simultaneous.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j4r2hxdf/) with minimal code reproducing the problem.

Here is the relevant minimal code:

html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="header">
          Atención 24 horas 0800-777-8101
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
        <a class="brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.jpg" class="logo" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="active"><a href="#">DSDSADSA</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">ADSASD</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

<div style="height:1000px;background-color:#ccc;padding:50px;"></div>
```

css:

```
.navbar {
  height: 110px;
}
div.header{
  text-align:right;
  height:50px;
}
```

And the most important, Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
      console.log('a');
      $('.navbar').animate({height: '60px'});
      $('div.header').slideUp();
    } else {
      console.log('b');
      $('.navbar').animate({height: '110px'});
      $('div.header').slideDown();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: if you want the navbar not to move why are you animating it in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, everytime you scroll when the `scrollTop` is greater than `0` it is applying:-

```
$('.navbar').animate({height: '110px'});
$('div.header').slideDown();
```

and not just when its up, (`height` and `slideUp`). This causes the else to fire multiple times. see the console for `a`

One way of fixing this is applying a class to `.header` to determine if you need to apply the animation. like so:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0 && !$('div.header').hasClass('hide')) {
      console.log('a');
      $('.navbar').animate({height: '60px'}, "fast");
      $('div.header').slideUp("fast").toggleClass('hide');
    } else if ($(document).scrollTop() == 0 && $('div.header').hasClass('hide')) {
      console.log('b');
      $('.navbar').animate({height: '110px'}, "fast");
      $('div.header').slideDown("fast").toggleClass('hide');
    }
  });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/j4r2hxdf/4/)

or you could use `data` or a variable, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Before you apply the animation or slideup  make  use of [stop](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) function to clear the queue.

```
$('div.header').stop();
$('.navbar').stop();
```

Check out the working demo for you code here [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nitish1604/j4r2hxdf/3/)

Comment: I did this only in `the scrollTop=0` case and it works good enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Determining if your `.navbar` is currently in the state of *animation* will do the trick, based on which you can decide NOT to animate.

Just add the following snippet which uses jQuery's `is()` method, and returns `false` if the `.navbar` is in the animation state:

```
  if($('.navbar').is(':animated')){
    return false;
  }
```

*[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/zopLnx17/)*